# svg clip-path doesn't work in iOS Cordova

Tags: cordova, svg, cordova-ios

I'm facing this strange behavior where `clip-path` works in every other platform, but doesn't in iOS Cordova:

[image]

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="1.1"
  class="h5"
  viewBox="0 0 70 100">
  <clipPath id="coverClip">
    <path
      id="coverClipPath"
      d="M70,35.2562008 C70,42.4737919 66.5942972,52.6435655 60.5861738,65.4439216 C56.2095414,74.768373 50.643657,84.9943895 45.264574,93.9783775 C43.1654827,97.7717745 39.2603357,100 35,100 C30.7809438,100 26.8884791,97.6699004 24.7718563,94.0388445 C19.2249726,84.6844942 13.7625927,74.6385335 9.41558364,65.3931905 C3.39819924,52.5952455 0,42.4721427 0,35.2562008 C0,25.9190207 3.7288895,17.2078912 10.2415755,10.4592775 C16.6851366,3.78229279 25.5311641,0 35,0 C44.4399672,0 53.2609177,3.75926488 59.6994217,10.3982874 C66.2784473,16.8839283 70,25.7605548 70,35.2562008 Z">
    </path>
  </clipPath>
  <image
    id="coverImgEl"
    clip-path="url(#coverClip)"
    width="70"
    height="100"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
    xlink:href="https://res.cloudinary.com/dsdoglmmy/image/upload/c_fill,h_72,w_52/v1488822655/experience/fc3d9183a513f18be7ba4ffd43ad6a6d.jpg">
  </image>
</svg>
```

If it's not supported in cordova ios, how do i achieve this there?